# Compare two list and get unique elements from first list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, variables

I have two lists

```
A=[1,3,5,6] 
B=[3,5,7]
```

I need to get only the elements that are part of A but not part of B. Thus, the result of this must be `Result= [1,6]`

I'm trying to get the difference, but the output I get is the following

```
Result = [i for i in A + B if i not in A or i not in B]
Result = [1,6,7]
```

How could I get `[1,6]` instead?

Comment: User set operations, something like this - set(A) - set(B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result = [i for i in A if i not in B]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use sets:

```
set(A) - set(B)
```

Sets comprise unique elements, and subtraction corresponds to set difference.